# Custom post archive page not opening 404 page

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have custom post type like this

```
register_post_type( 'workforce_archive',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Workforce Archives' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Workforce Archive' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'workforce_archive'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => false,
            'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author' ]
        )
    );
```

And also have a file archive-workforce_archives.php but still I am getting 404 page when visit this URL "http://taliestrategies.local/workforce_archives".

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you flushed permalinks by visiting _Settings > Permalinks_?

Comment: Permalinks set to post_name and what do you mean by flush. Should I change it?